# Как откорректировать радиус поиска мест в google api android?

Tags: android, google-maps-api

При отправлении запроса использую [параметр radius=300](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search), который должен показывать места в радиусе 300 метров от моего местоположения:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    stringBuilder.append("location=").append(mLatitude).append(",").append(mLongitude);
    stringBuilder.append("&keyword=пятерочка | магнит");
    stringBuilder.append("&language=ru");
    stringBuilder.append("&radius=300");
    stringBuilder.append("&sensor=true");
```

Тот же [Circle](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle) при значении 300 метров от моего местоположения:

```
Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(latLng)
            .radius(300).strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 255, 0, 0))
            .fillColor(Color.argb(50, 255, 0, 0)));
```

В документации говорится, что и то значение, и другое возвращается в метрах те по сути и в запросе 300 метров, и в Круге 300 метров, но по факту получаю вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы радиус, отображаемый кругом, соответствовал радиусу запроса?

Comment: Добавлю вопрос, вдруг кто увидит. Можно ли получить базу данных таких мест, которые я хочу использовать в своей игре? Просто по документации можно запрашивать места с радиусом максимум в 500, а полной базы данных я не нашел. Хотя бы идентификаторы на места с указанием его типов

Comment: @danilshik 
1) Максимальный радиус в запросе 50000 метров, ознакомьтесь внимательнее с документацией (гиперссылку оставил в начале поста)

2) Идентификаторы мест, их тип, их id, точные имена и т.д. получаем в json ответе, не вижу проблемы парсить этот ответ, брать нужные типы данных и забивать их в базу (в моем случае использовался List)

Comment: и что мне для каждой рандомной точки такое производить? Для всего мира будет довольно проблемно). Насчет 50000, извиняюсь, по памяти писал).

Comment: @danilshik Думаю, что если грамотно указать в параметрах запроса type & keyword, то поиск значительно сузится только до конкретных мест. Я делал следующее: искал одно необходимое место и на его основе подгонял поиск под остальные похожие места в необходимом мне радиусе. К примеру: для поиска 2 ближайших продуктовых магазинов я использую только их имена ("&keyword=пятерочка | магнит"), если расширить радиус до 50км, то он найдет наиболее релевантные места, в которых указан этот параметр. Примерно так это и работает. Больше конкретики в запросе и он вам выдаст необходимое.

Comment: @danilshik Еще есть мысль, что полученные места можно проверять прямо внутри кода и добавлять в бд места, которые прошли эту проверку (для проверки можно использовать  сравнение по имени)

Comment: Это все хорошо, но вы не много не поняли мою идею. Я хочу получить базу данных всех зданий, чтобы на основе этих данных создать экономическую стратегию, с различными ценами в зависимости от города и других параметров. Мне необходима именно база данных, чтобы она у меня хранилась. Да я могу ставить точку на карте и искать места в радиусе, проверять наличие в моей базе и если они отсутствуют, то добавлять. Но чтобы сделать для всей страны хотя бы, то можно замучиться, а о мире уже можно и не говорить.

Comment: Как идея, можно получить каким либо образом координаты центра городов, и на максимальном радиусе искать места и добавлять в БД. Но возможно варианты, что некоторые объекты в радиус не попадут

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80876/discussion-between-trashds-and-danilshik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, в документации так-же говорится, что подходящие места могут находится на небольшом расстоянии от радиуса, вот он и находит лишние места. Решается это простым добавлением цикла на проверку расстояния во время добавления маркера на карту:

```
if (distance < radius){
                markerOptions.title(name + " : " + distance + " метров");
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
```

Или, как мне ответили на англоязычном форуме:

```
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
//in build.gradle (Module:app)

//Вычисляем расстояние для маркера внутри границы
for (Place place: allPlaces) {
float distance = (float) SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(centreLatLng, place.getLatLng());
if (distance <= 300) {
    Marker placeMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(place.getLatLng())
        .title(place.getName())
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
        .anchor(0.5 f, 1.0 f));
    }
}
```